# Angular Universal and prerendered routes

Tags: angular, angular-universal, prerender

I was just watching a video explaining about Angular Universal and it actually taught me something I didn't know. You can add routes to your **angular.json** file that will be prerendered. This is great for me, because a lot of routes are routed to the same component, but uses a headless CMS to generate the content.
So I updated my **routes** array in **angular.json** like this:

```
"prerender": {
  "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "sxp-marketing-website:build:production",
    "serverTarget": "sxp-marketing-website:server:production",
    "routes": [
      "/contact",
      "/contact/thankyou",
      "/innovation-directory",
      "/locations",
      "/managed-service",
      "/pricing",
      "/unconfirmed"
    ]
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {}
  }
},
```

Nice; then I ran `npm run prerender` and it did generate my files:

[image]

Really nice, so then I ran `npm run serve:ssr` which was pretty much instant and I navigated my browser to **http://localhost:4000** and navigated through my site. In the video I was watching, it stated that as you traverse through your routes, if you look at the **elements** tab in chrome and scroll to the bottom you will see a comment like this:

[image]

The issue I have is that I wasn't. Infact, it just seems to use the normal client version (with SSR ofcourse) which bothered me.

The page I was looking at was `http://localhost:4000/managed-service` which is clearly defined in my **angular.json** file. I remembered that the prerendered file is generated inside a folder named after the route, and it's actually an **index.html** file, so I updated my url to this `http://localhost:4000/managed-service/index.html` and it changes the route back to `http://localhost:4000/managed-service` but it does show the comment.

I am now wondering if there is something wrong with my **web.config**; perhaps it's not routing correctly. Or maybe there is something I am missing.

Can anyone help?

PS: This is my **web.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
        </staticContent>
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^main.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <remove segment="bin"/>
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run `npm run app-name:prerender` or `yarn prerender` then run the server file created at `dist/{app-name}/server/.main.js` with this command `node dist/{app-name}/server/main.js`.

Running `npm run dev:ssr` will actually rebuild the application and overwrite the prerendered files you previously created.

See: https://github.com/mgechev/hybrid-rendering

The `main.js` server file that is built from `npm run prerender` is configured to serve a hybrid app. `npm run dev:ssr` will build a server file that will only SSR your app.

Comment: And in production? Will running `ng build --prod && ng run sxp-marketing-website:server:production` not generate the prerendered pages?

Comment: No - to prerender _any_ routes in your app, you must run `npm run app-name:prerender`.  You'll notice, though, that `npm run app-name:prerender` will build the app in the production environment. The build files in the `dist` directory will be ready for prod.